# Select a random date within specific range

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

How can I select a random date within a specific inclusive range, let's say '1950-01-01' and '1999-12-31' with SQL Server?

Comment: Are you trying to build data for multiple rows at the same time, or just a single date?  I just wonder if you're trying to build up some test data to insert into a table.

Comment: Hi Jeff. I need random dates within a range in order to run a loop and populate a test table with random dates of birth. :)

Comment: How many rows of data do you need?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This will give you 1000 rows of data to insert.

```
DECLARE @D1 DATE = '19500101'
DECLARE @D2 DATE = '19991231'

   ;WITH E00(N) AS (SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1),
        E02(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E00 a, E00 b),
        E04(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E02 a, E02 b),
        E08(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E04 a, E04 b),
        E16(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E08 a, E08 b),
        E32(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E16 a, E16 b),
   cteTally(N) AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY N) FROM E32)
   SELECT TOP 1000
    DATEADD(DAY,ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) % (1+DATEDIFF(DAY,@D1,@D2)),@D1)
   FROM  cteTally
```

NB: This answer originally used `ABS(CAST(CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(4) AS INT))` to generate the random numbers. Unlike `RAND()` which is only evaluated once per statement this is evaluated once per row so would work.

However it seems that the Query Optimiser does not realise this and treats it as a constant. For the purposes of generating random data this probably won't matter (unless you are populating a column constrained by a foreign key)

but I just tested the alternative `ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID()))` to see if there was any performance benefit of one over the other.

Typical speeds to generate 1,000,000 rows using the numbers table above and select the `MAX` value (to avoid overhead of returning all these rows to the client)

```
ABS(CAST(CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(4) AS INT))
/*CPU time = 4180 ms,  elapsed time = 4395 ms.*/

ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID()))
/*CPU time = 953 ms,  elapsed time = 1163 ms.*/

(SELECT 1) /*A constant value just to get a baseline*/
/*CPU time = 499 ms,  elapsed time = 457 ms.*/
```

So unless you need a cryptographically secure PRNG it's probably best avoided!

Comment: Hi Martin. Thank you very much. It seems that If I want to have even '1992-12-31' I have to declare @d2 as '2000-01-01', otherwise the query doesn't include last day.

Comment: @nick - I already changed it to `1+DATEDIFF(DAY,@D1,@D2)` to fix that problem.

Comment: You're simply great:) Thanks for all the time you've dedicated me. I really appreciate it. Thanks again Martin.

Comment: Ops. I've finished my daily upvotes. I'll even upvote it tomorrow :)

Answer (score 15):

```
select DateAdd(d, ROUND(DateDiff(d, '1950-01-01', '1999-12-31') * RAND(), 0), '1950-01-01')
```

**EDIT**

If this is to be executed as part of a statement that returns multiple rows or as part of update, the RAND() would return single value for the whole resultset. For that case RAND(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) can be used.

```
select DateAdd(d, ROUND(DateDiff(d, '1950-01-01', '1999-12-31') * RAND(), 0), '1950-01-01'),
       DateAdd(d, ROUND(DateDiff(d, '1950-01-01', '1999-12-31') * RAND(CHECKSUM(NEWID())), 0), '1950-01-01')
from master..spt_values where type = 'P'
```

Comment: This appears to be randomly selecting either 1/1/1950 or 12/31/1999, but not any dates in between.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your reply. I've tried your query but it always returns one of those two values as already written.

Comment: Modify above to e.g.
`select DateAdd(d, ROUND(DateDiff(d, '1950-01-01', '1999-12-31') * RAND(CHECKSUM(NEWID())), 0), '1950-01-01')`
to get random values as part of e.g. an update statement.